# Access one dict from 2 functions

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to access a list from 2 functions , but the problem is they will both access the same data.

My ideas are not working , the original idea was this:

```
mylist= ['string1','string2'.......'stringx']

def func(string):
....

def spawn_thread(string):
Thread(target = func(string)).start()
...

def start():
for something in mylist:
      spawn_thread(something)
```

On the first time string1 is used , i need on the second run string2 in a different thread.

First thread:

```
func(string1) -> func(string3) -> func(string5)
```

second thread:

```
func(string2) -> func(string4) -> string(string6)
```

Or is there any other way / better way to achieve this ?

Comment: dict = ['string1','string2'] is not a dictionary, but a list of strings

Comment: @LetzerWille thanks changed!

Comment: what are you actually doing?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham sorry updated again

Comment: the general way to communicate with threads is to use a `queue.Queue` object. This question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/python-multithreading-for-dummies